# Escape character appears in the string

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I am writing a piece of code in Visual c# 2010 to generate a string. This string needs to contain backslashes \ and speech marks ".

**I have tried the following ways of doing this:**

```
string StringOutputVariable;
string StringVariable = "hello world";
StringOutputVariable = "\"C:\\Program Files\\some program\\some program.exe\" " + StringVariable;
```

and

```
string StringOutputVariable;
string StringVariable = "hello world";
StringOutputVariable = @"""C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe"" " + StringVariable;
```

**however they both put the escape characters in the output string:**

> \"C:\\Program Files\\some program\\some program.exe\" hello world

and

> \"C:\\Program Files\\some program\\some program.exe\" hello world

**what I want it to output is:**

> "C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe" hello world

**Why does my code output the escape characters into the string?**

Thanks in advance
Graham

Comment: check once again ...........finally you will get "C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe" hello world

Comment: If you look in the debugger, it should still show the extra \. Print it to console to see what you should see.

Comment: Use the debugger's text visualizer, click the spy-glass icon.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringOutputVariable = "\"" +
        @"C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe\" + "\" " + StringVariable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies all, now sorted. i think we can put this down to a 'chair to keyboard error'

Comment: lol some days are that way.  I think it took me 2 edits to get on the screen what was in my head.  Have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking at the strings in the debugger. The debugger will show strings as if they were string literals, that is, with quotation marks and backslashes escaped. The string is like you intended it to be.

You can easily check by simply printing the string to the console or putting it somewhere on a Form.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all, now sorted. i think we can put this down to a 'chair to keyboard error'

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe";

string result = string.Format("{0}{1}{0} hello world", "\"", path);

// you can check it: MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies all, now sorted. i think we can put this down to a 'chair to keyboard error'.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger shows strings if they have [`string literals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Try like this;

```
    string StringOutputVariable;
    string StringVariable = "hello world";
    StringOutputVariable = "\"" + @"C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe\" + "\"" + StringVariable;
    Console.WriteLine(StringOutputVariable);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/OKGbVX).

Output is:

```
"C:\Program Files\some program\some program.exe\"hello world
```

Comment: Well... i now feel sheepish. LOL. Thanks